# What is regulatory promoter?

Tags: molecular-biology, terminology, transcription

I came across this term in University question paper.

> What is the difference between core promoter and regulatory promoter?

I have googled (Web, Scholar and Books) it but couldn't find any information from any authentic source.

Comment: I don't understand this. Promoters are regulatory per se, so this doesn't male sense to me.

Comment: @Chris I don't know, may be it has something to do with [Proximal and Distal promoters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promoter_(genetics)#Elements).I've edited the post with the question I found.